# How to compare password before change in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

i have a problem to compare old and new password when user try to change their password. I created a controller that can help user to do that but i can not run or call the API. so, i need help that anybody can help me to do this, some suggestions or any advices would be nice.

```
// Change password EDITED PERFERCTION
exports.changePassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByPk(req.params.user_id);
    console.log(user);
    var body = req.body;
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send("invalid value");
    }
    

    bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password, async function (err, isMatch) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(400).send("Password not matched!");
      }

      
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
      const newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(body.newPassword, salt);
      user.set(
        { password: newPassword, updated_date: moment() },
        {
          where: {
            user_id: user.user_id,
          },
        }
      );

      await user.save();
      return res.status(200).send("Password Changed successfully!");
    });

    
  } catch (error) {
    res.send("An error occured");
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Please help me to compare password before change. thank you for your help

Comment: What difficulties are you facing in your current code?
Please provide proper details.

Comment: Could you explain your problem, please?

Comment: my problem now that i wanna check old and new password before change

Comment: you have to compare body password with db stored password first, if they matched then create and hash new password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this to check old password first and then update it

```
exports.changePassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByPk(req.params.user_id)
    var body = req.body
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send('invalid value')
    }

    bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password, async function (err, isMatch) {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      }
      if (!isMatch) throw new Error('Password not matched!')

      // if not error and password matched then we will hash password
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
      const newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(body.newPassword, salt)

      user.set({ password: newPassword, updated_at: now() })

      await user.save()
    })

    res.status(200).send('Password Changed successfully!')
  } catch (error) {
    res.send('An error occured')
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```